# Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу при приводе матрицы к треугольному виду

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы

Возникает данная ошибка при выполнении программы. Само задание звучит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image]
 Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить? Догадываюсь что вышел за пределы массива но не понимаю где и как пофиксить =/

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    double r = 0;

    cin >> m >> n;

    double **a = new double*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        a[i] = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {
        for (int j = k + 1; j < m + 2; j++)
        {
            r = a[j][k]/a[k][k];
            for (int i = k; i < m + 1; i++)
            {
                a[j][i] = a[j][i] - r*a[k][i];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        delete []a[i];


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в коде ошибка здесь

` for (int j = k + 1; j < n+2; j++)
        {
            o = a[k][j]/a[k][k];`

Вы явно обращаетесь за пределы по второй размерности

Comment: а как исправить не подскажете?

Comment: Найдите алгоритм, как привести матрицу к треугольному виду и перепишите алгоритм правильно

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < m- 1; i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) { o = a[i][j]/a[j][j]; a[i]-=a[j]*o; } } я исправил вроде, но теперь выдает ошибку error C2296: *: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "double *" в строке a[i]-=a[j]*o; Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь) 
Со всем вроде разобрался)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    double r = 0;

    cin >> m >> n;

    double **a = new double*[m];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        a[i] = new double[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cin >> a[i][j];

    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        for (int i = k + 1; i < m; i++)
        {
            r = a[i][k]/a[k][k];
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] = a[i][j] - r*a[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        delete []a[i];


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Логично, что ошибка возникает из-за обращения к памяти за пределами созданных массивов. Например в этом цикле

```
for (int k = 0; k < m - 1; k++)
{
    for (int j = k + 1; j < n+2; j++)
    {
        o = a[k][j]/a[k][k];
        for (int i = k; i < m + 1; i++)
        {
            a[j][i] = a[j][i] - o * a[k][i];
        }
    }
}
```

при `j` равным `n+1` уже  этом предложении в теле циклов

```
        o = a[k][j]/a[k][k]
```

имеет место обращение к несущетвующему элементу  с индексом `a[k][n+1]`

Так что проверяйте корректность записи циклов и используемых индексов при обращении к элементам массивов.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < m- 1; i++)
 {
  for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
  {
   o = a[i][j]/a[j][j];
   a[i]-=a[j]*o;
  }
 }

я исправил вроде, но теперь выдает ошибку error C2296: *: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "double *" в строке a[i]-=a[j]*o; Как это исправить?

Comment: @Roman  a[j] - это указатель. Поэтому данная операция a[j]*o очевидно не корректная,.

Comment: я опять тут код поменял, но возникла еще одна ошибка, не поможете пожалуйста? таким тупым себя давно не чувствовал =/