# Программа которая считывает текст из консоли и выводит только строки не содержащие двузначных чисел

Tags: c++, строки

Здравствуйте. Вот такое задание у меня было и я вроде написал код, но он почему то не выводит нужную мне строку, а точнее вообще ничего не выводит...., не могли бы вы мне указать на мои ошибки и помочь его исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char digits[] = "1234567890";
    char s1[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    gets_s(s1);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(s1); j++)
        {
            char *s3 = s1;
            while(!isdigit(*s3))
                s3++;
            int k = strspn(s3,digits);
            if (k == 2)
                puts(s1);
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В чем смысл этого загадочного цикла    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    gets_s(s1);? Или вам платят за количество введенных знаков в программе?

Comment: Мало того, что вы функцию gets_s неправильно вызываете, так такой функции нет в C++.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала вам следует включить заголовки `<stdio.h>` и `<cstring>`, так как вы используете функции, объявленные в этих заголовках, как, например, функцию `strspn`.

Данный цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
gets_s(s1);
```

не имеет смысла. И кроме того в нем используется некорректно С функция, которая между прочим не поддерживается стандартом C++, `gets_s`. Эта функция имеет два параметра, как видно из ее объявления

```
char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);
```

вы же вызываете эту функцию с одним аргументом. Поэтому уже начиная с этого места ваша программа имеет неопределенное поведение.

Если же эта функция с одним параметром объявлена в качестве расширения языка в некотором компиляторе, то лучше все же на это не полагаться, так как ваш код в этом случае будет не переносим и не соответствовать стандарту C++.

У вас не должно быть этого цикла. Вам следует считывать строку в следующим за этим цикле. И используйте стандартные функции C++, как, например, `std::getline`, вместо функции `gets_s`.

Данный цикл

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(s1); j++)
```

также некорректный, так как считанная строка может быть короче, чем длина массива `s1`. Вместо значения `sizeof( s1 )` вам следует по крайней мере использовать значение, возвращаемое функцией `strlen`. А еще лучше просто ориентироваться на завершающий нуль строки, как условие прекращения цикла.

В этом предложении

```
        if (k == 2)
            puts(s1);
```

вы пытаетесь вывести строку, которая как раз содержит по крайней мере одно двухзначное число, хотя по условию задания вы такие строки должны пропускать.

При использовании стандартных C функций таких, как `strspn` и `strcspn`, программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 256;
    char s[N];
    const char *digits = "0123456789";

    while ( std::cin.getline( s, sizeof( s ) ) && s[0] != '\0' )
    {
        const char *p = s;
        size_t n = 0;

        do
        {
            n = std::strcspn( p, digits );
            p += n;
            n = std::strspn( p, digits );
            p += n;
        } while ( *p && n != 2 );

        if ( n != 2 ) std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);` - насколько я помню, там есть и другое объявление - через шаблон для массивов фиксированного размера.

Comment: @Qwertiy Нет такой функции в стандарте C++. Может быть она где-то и объявлена, в качестве расширения языка некоторого компилятора, но тем не менее, лучше на это не полагаться, а пользоваться стандартными функциями.

Comment: Я ничего не говорил про стандарт. Да, это расширение MSVS. Но перегрузок две - та, что в ответе, и та, что в вопросе. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB1Id.png Скриншот, т. к. там какое-то шаманство с макросами в объявлении, из которого замучаешься доставать: `__DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_SECURE_FUNC_0_0(
    char*, gets_s,
    char, _Buffer)`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7gbcV5Vq

Comment: @Roman Не за что. Спрашивайте еще.:)

Comment: А не могли бы вы помочь если вам не трудно мне в этой теме:
http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596957/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2